# R markdown: Using R code within latex table

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I have a finished latex table like this one loaded into r markdown.

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
\hline 
$\textbf{Details}$ &    \\ 
\midrule[1pt]
\specialrule{2pt}{-2pt}{-2pt}
\specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0.5pt} 
Name der Sitzung &  $A$
\\ \hline 
erstellt am & $XXXXXX$ \\ \hline 
erstellt von & $x$ \\ \hline 
Zeitpunkt Auswertung & $x$ \\ \hline 
Anzahl Teilnehmer & $x$ \\ \hline 
Anzahl Stimmen & $x$ \\ \hline 
Anzahl Fragen & $x$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

The part $XXXXX$ is supposed to be replaced by the following R code: DATA$TABLE[[1]]$a[[1]].
How can i do that?

When I plug in

´´´{r}
Table[[1]]$a[[1]]
´´´

for $XXXXX$, I get an error message:

output file: dynmaicMarkdown.knit.md

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.124 #
# NULL

Fehler: LaTeX failed to compile dynmaicMarkdown.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See dynmaicMarkdown.log for more info.
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In has_crop_tools() :
Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: pdfcrop, ghostscript
-> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled.
Ausführung angehalten

Comment: Mark it as inline code:  \`r DATA$TABLE[[1]]$a[[1]]\`.

Comment: do you by any chance also know how to use for loops in that context? 
like  
```for (j in 1:  x){ 
`r Table[[2]][[j,1]]` & `r Table[[2]][[j,2]]` & `r Table[[j]][[1,3]]` & `r Table[[2]][[j,4]]`\\ \hline }```

Comment: All of the R code has to be within \`r ... \`.  So you could build up the string you want there using `paste()`, and then insert the whole thing at once.  Or even better:  use `kable()` or one of the other table-writing functions to write the whole table.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I will try the paste thing. The Problem is that I have to stick to a certain company-wide table-layout. Special thickness of lines etc. This is what I have a template for. Is it possible to throw throw that much Detail into Kable?

Comment: No, not just with `kable()`, but it may be possible with `kableExtra`, or one of the other choices.

Comment: Ok good. How exactly could that ```paste () ``` thing work?